# Clicking on ImageView and view behind him at the same time

Tags: android, imageview, android-windowmanager

i have windowManager that is top of all views and in windowManager there is ImageView, how can i click on ImageView and screen behind him at the same time ? any suggestions ? thanks in advance.

Comment: you cannot start `WindowManager`, `WindowManager` is a system service, it is not started by you

Comment: i've tried to get position on imageView and imitate on screen by Runtime.getRuntime().exec("input tap " + e.getX() + " " + e.getY());
But Runtime is slow.

Comment: @pskink thanks for correction.